# Google maps v3 does'nt work anymore in web app, with Android 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch

please if someone has the same problem :
 when developpping a mobile app with Google maps v3 (javascript) into a device Android 4.0.4, it doesn't work anymore. My App had working a year ago but in theses months it show in my Eclipse's Console this error :

```
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 at https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/17/13/intl/fr_ALL/%7Bmain,drawing%7D.js:34
```

then this error :

`Uncaught Error: undefined is not a function ... sencha-touch.js:18`

NB: My app works fine in my browser Chrome !!!
    I tried to develop a sample code in index.html that work in the browser, but after deploy it with eclipse in my phone it doesn't work !! so the problem is my phone or something is changed in the politic of using googlemaps in android !! 
Thanks !!